# Mokito wont return a stubbed value

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito

[image]I started TDD  recently and it has slowed my progress, I m trying to stub a return value with Mockito, but i keep getting "null is not a subtype of Future-dynamic' not sure what i did wrong, here is my setup

```
class ImageSelectorMock extends Mock implements ImageSelector {}
getImageSelectorMock({logo}) {
 _unregisterIfRegistered<ImageSelector>();
 var imageSelector = ImageSelectorMock();
 if (logo != null) {
   when(imageSelector.businessLogo).thenReturn('string');
   when(imageSelector.uploadImage(null, 'folder'))
    .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async =>
       Future.value('send this')
   );
 }

locator.registerSingleton<ImageSelector>(imageSelector);
return imageSelector;
}

setupService() {
 //getAuthServiceMock();
  //getFirestoreServiceMock();
  //getNavigationServiceMock();
  getImageSelectorMock();
}

void _unregisterIfRegistered<T extends Object>() {
   if (locator.isRegistered<T>()) {
     locator.unregister<T>();
   }
}
```

getImageSelectorMock takes an optional arg "logo" to check if imageSelector.uploadImage  is called. Also, I'm using a locator/get_it package

```
group('RegistrationviewmodelTest -', () {

setUp(() => {setupService()});
 
  test('when business logo is  NOT null => uplaodImage should be called', () async {
      // final navigation = getNavigationServiceMock();
      // final fireStore = getFirestoreServiceMock();

      final imageSelector = await getImageSelectorMock(logo: "test");
      final model = RegistraionViewModel();

      await model.createBusiness({
        'title': "text",
        'description': "text",
      });
      verify(imageSelector.uploadImage('', 'upload'));
      // verify(navigation.navigateTo());
    }); 
});

//  uploadImage  does
  Future uploadImage(file, folder) async {
   // String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    String fileName = basename(file.path);
    final firebaseStorageRef =
       FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$folder/$fileName');
    final uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(file);
    final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    return taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) => value);
}
```

uploadImage is just an image picker that returns download Url from fire storege.
Thanks for helping out!!

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can include? It would be helpful to know where your "null is not a subtype..." error is coming from

Comment: I have added a snip of the stack trace